# What is this tiny translucent worm I found on my desk?

Tags: species-identification, species

I found this tiny critter crawling vertically up my speakers. It seems to crawl like a caterpillar, but strangely, every now and then, it stops, rears-up and look/ feel around.

It looks sort of grey/ translucent from a distance with a maybe orange-ish head and tail-tip, however, looking at it from above, it seems to have a black center.

It was kind of hard to take a clear picture, but I hope it helps.

P.S. Got it in a glass before, just because I've never seen anything like it before. My friend said it might be an alien.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is a lepidopteran, most likely in the family, Geometridae. An "inchworm". https://www.thoughtco.com/geometer-moths-inchworms-and-loopers-1968193